# Scrapy multiple requests and fill single item

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to make 2 request to different urls and put that information to the same item. I have tried this method, but the result is written in different rows. The callbacks **returns item**. I have tried many methods but none seems to work.

```
def parse_companies(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    if data:
        item = ThalamusItem()
        for company in data:
            comp_id = company["id"]

            url = self.request_details_URL + str(comp_id) + ".json"
            request = Request(url, callback=self.parse_company_details)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

            url2 = self.request_contacts + str(comp_id)
            yield Request(url2, callback=self.parse_company_contacts, meta={'item': item})
```

Comment: You may look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498623/3140273

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since scrapy is asynchronious you need to chain your requests manually. For transfering data between requests you can use Request's `meta` attribute:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = dict()
    item['name'] = 'foobar'
    yield request('http://someurl.com', self.parse2,
                  meta={'item': item})

def parse2(self, response):
    print(response.meta['item'])
    # {'name': 'foobar'}
```

In your case you end up with a split chain when you should have one continuous chain.
Your code should look something like this:

```
def parse_companies(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    if not data:
        return
    for company in data:
        item = ThalamusItem()
        comp_id = company["id"]
        url = self.request_details_URL + str(comp_id) + ".json"
        url2 = self.request_contacts + str(comp_id)
        request = Request(url, callback=self.parse_details,
                          meta={'url2': url2, 'item': item})
        yield request

def parse_details(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    url2 = response.meta['url2']
    item['details'] = ''  # add details
    yield Request(url2, callback=self.parse_contacts, meta={'item': item})

def parse_contacts(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['contacts'] = ''  # add details
    yield item
```

Comment: One question, I have a problem that it seems details are being done first then it comes to the contact information. It ends up messing up everything. The contact information is all over the place and not where it should belong. The code I am using is literally the same you use here.

Comment: @DainiusPreimantas hmm, there seems to be an error in the my example. The item should be created in __every__ loop, see my edit. Otherwise what happens is that we keep modifying one reference and end up with chaotic mess.