# Is there best way to scrape multiple pages in different structure in same domain with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape some pages in same domain but **different structure** with scrapy.

```
http://example.com/page1
http://example.com/page2
http://example.com/page3
```

I found this answer and now using this.
（Passing argument is understandable for me）

[Scrapy multiple requests and fill single item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922961/scrapy-multiple-requests-and-fill-single-item)

```
def start_requests(self): #This refers scrapy tutrials
        urls = [
            'http://example.com/page1',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    data_page1 = response.xpath("//body")
    yield scrapy.Request('http://example.com/page2', self.parse2,
                  meta={'data_page1': data_page1})

def parse2(self, response):
    data_page2 = response.xpath("//body")
    yield scrapy.Request('http://example.com/page3', self.parse3,
                  meta={'data_page1': data_page1,'data_page2': data_page2})

def parse3(self, response):
    data_page3 = response.xpath("//body")
    yield {
       'data_page1' : response.meta['data_page1'],
       'data_page2' : response.meta['data_page2'],
       'data_page3' : data_page3
    }
```

But I think this is not good code...

Is there the best way scrape multiple pages more efficiently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't find this code bad and use this approach all the time. And after all, it's mentioned in [FAQ](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-scrape-an-item-with-attributes-in-different-pages) as a suggested way of collecting data from multiple pages. So if you actually need to gather data from multiple pages and yield it as a single item, then this approach is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thank you! I'm relieved to hear that!