# How can I collect multiple items from two pages and merge them into a single database row multiple times with one new item?

Tags: python, scrapy

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to Scrapy.

I already made a working version of the spider. But, it takes only one image. How to make a link to the image taken from a new page and added to the rest of the elements and add in the database? In this case, as many times as there will be images.

At the end of the code I wrote what I wanted to do. I also made a visual scheme.

[Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvEeo.png)

Spider code with comments in the end:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'MySpider'
download_delay = 20
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
start_urls = ['https://example.com/page/']
visited_urls = []



#Take posts urls from page
def parse(self, response):
    lua_script = """
        function main(splash, args)

        assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))

        -- requires Splash 2.3
        while not splash:select(".image-group") do
        splash:wait(40)
        end
        return {html=splash:html()}
        end
            """
    if response.url not in self.visited_urls:
        self.visited_urls.append(response.url)

    for post_link in response.xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]/div/div/article/ul/li/@data-url').extract():
            url = urljoin(response.url, post_link)
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_post, endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': lua_script})




    next_pages = response.xpath('//*[contains(@rel, "next")]/@href').extract()
    next_page = next_pages[-1]
    next_page_url = urljoin(response.url+'/', next_page)
    yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)





def parse_post(self, response):

    items = MyItem()
    link = response.xpath('//*[@property="og:url"]/@content').extract()
    title = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-header"]/h1/text()').extract()
    tags = response.xpath('//*[@id="widget-tags"]/div/a/@data-tag').extract()
    category = ('Category')
    price = response.xpath('//*[@name="twitter:data1"]/@content').extract()


    items['link'] = ''.join(link).strip()
    items['title'] = ''.join(title).strip()
    items['tags'] = ', '.join(tags).strip()
    items['category'] = ''.join(category).strip()

    yield items



### Go to page(url = item['link'] + '/images/screenshot1')
# Take ImageLink = response.xpath('//*[@class="preview"]/img/@src').extract()
# Add previous items from def parse_post (link, title, tags, category, price)
# yield all items (link, title, tags, category, price, imagelink) (To add to the database)



### Go to page(url = item['link'] + '/images/screenshot2')
# Take ImageLink = response.xpath('//*[@class="preview"]/img/@src').extract()
# Add previous items from def parse_post (link, title, tags, category, price)
# yield all items (link, title, tags, category, price, imagelink) (To add to the database)



### Go to page(url = item['link'] + '/images/screenshot3')
# Take ImageLink = response.xpath('//*[@class="preview"]/img/@src').extract()
# Add previous items from def parse_post (link, title, tags, category, price)
# yield all items (link, title, tags, category, price, imagelink) (To add to the database)


# And do it as many times as there will be screenshots (A number of screenshots of different)
```

Comment: See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922961/scrapy-multiple-requests-and-fill-single-item/44923416#44923416