# How to crawl a page in Scrapy where part of the data is fetched later through ajax?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl page A, In which there is a value I need to POST to page B, and get the results and append it to the data from page A.

More specifically the phone number will be revealed when the user clicked on a masked text.

In Scrapy how can I start another request in the `parse` method AND append the parsed data to the main data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is using python `requests` during your parse.

```py
import requests

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

## your spider code
....
    def parse(self, response):
       URL = response.xpath("selector of URL").get()
       r = requeste.post(URL, data={"key" : value} )
       result = r.json().get("new_key") # if response is json othersiwse you have to parse the result. 
       data['new_key] = result
      yield data
```

but if it is a more complicated problem you can use `scrapy.Items` you can find an example here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44923416/2754195)
and read  more about [`Items` here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html)